# Wondering how to do floating point binary calculations

Tags: binary, decimal

One of my review questions is as follows:
 Give a float that is represented in a byte using: bit 7 as the sign bit, bits 4-6 as the exponent in excess-3 and bits 0-3 as the mantissa.

What would 11000000 & 10100100 represent in decimal?

Lastly I've been trying to figure out how to do 4.25 and I myself had reached 001110001 in 9 bits. (Must I use 9 bits to represent this number in binary?)

Comment: Excess-3 defines 4 bits for the exponent, not 3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess-3

Comment: So than my review question contains errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that XS-3 is defined on 4 bits - I don't see any particular problem with narrowing it to 3 bits - my calculations are as follows:

11000000(2) = -2(10)

10100100(2) = -0.625(10)

To represent 4.25(10) I need only 8 bits - 01010001(2):

sign bit is 0;

exponent is 101(2) = 5(10), which in XS-3 means a value of 2;

mantissa is 0001.

Value = 1.0001(2) * 2^2 = 100.01(2) = 4.25(10)